# release notification not working for Azure VSTS pipeline for group email

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

[image]

I have tried to add a group email for a custom email address for the release pipeline but still no email, is this a vsts bug or I am doing something wrong

the release pipeline name and stage name are correct , I've verified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try configuring the [Delivery Setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/concepts-email-recipients?view=vsts).

[image]

[image]

> The following delivery settings are available for a group or team:
>
> 1. Deliver to email address: notifications are delivered to a specific email address.
> 2. Deliver to individual members: notifications are
>      delivered to each member of the group or team. This is usually the
>      default option. See the section on "team expansion" below for more
>      details on how this option works.
> 3. Do not deliver: notifications are not delivered by default.

From this you could try the **Deliver to email address**

Comment: Thanks , I ended up using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask